# Android automative system image not available

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Why Android automative system image is not available to create an emulator?

[image]

Comment: For testing see: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing. Note that there are two different instructions for the different version of DHU.

Answer (score 1):

Android Automotive emulator :-> you need to add system image of polestar and for that select Tools > SDK Manager
Then , Click the SDK Update Sites tab
Now Click on Add Icon

Enter Name and Url for image

Name: Polestar 2 System Image
URL: https://developer.polestar.com/sdk/polestar2-sys-img.xml

Comment: If you click on one of the device definitions in your last screen link, you'll reach the empty list screen that OP is complaining about, if you are running Android Studio 4.1.1. Feel free to delete answer if it just confirms OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the system image should be available by default in the SDK Manager.

`Tools->SDK Manager->Android SDK`.

Under `Tools->SDK Manager->Android SDK->SDK Tools` you can install the `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator`

Under `Tools->SDK Manager->Android SDK->SDK Update Sites` you should be able to see the system image name and urls. If you don't find you can add them as below

- **Android Automotive System Images:**    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-automotive/sys-img2-1.xml
- **Android System Images:**   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml
- **Intel HAXM:** https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml
- **Google API add-on System Images:**    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml
- **Google API with Playstore System Images:**    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img2-1.xml